# Writing Non soap web service

Tags: windows, web-services, rest, tomcat

Please let me know how to write a non soap web service. On the web I could find many tutorials to develop SOAP and REST based web services. But nothing really helpful for non soap. I would like to add custom http handling.

I am looking forward to host it on tomcat on a Windows machine. But any feasible options are welcome.

Comment: A website IS a web service. SOAP just happens to be one of the MANY methods of providing data from a site, layered on top of HTTP. Your question is too vague/broad.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achive? In general a RESTful service is a non-SOAP service... and what you mean by 'custom http handling'?

Answer (score 0):

REST services are by far simpler to get a start on. You did not specify whether you are interested in a particular language but you tagged your question with the [tomcat] tag, so I can suggest Java. REST is a part of Java specifications now and a good way to start is the [Oracle Java EE tutorial on REST](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html).